# How to color the background with event.target?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js, frontend

I'm working with drag-and-drop in my application, in this case I can drag users to different projects in a list.

Now i'm styling the UI and I want to colour the background of my item-list, but it doesn't really work. When I drag the item over `<v-list-item-avatar>`  or `<v-list-item-title>`  the background of the list-item does not change its colour. Only by dragging over `<v-list-item>` . So it's a little bit buggy.

I tried different approaches, but none of them were helpful. How can I optimize the approach to get the expected result?

Vue-Snippet:

```
<v-list-item-group v-model="selectedProjectItem">
          <v-list-item
            @drop='onDrop($event, project)'
            @dragover.prevent
            @dragenter.prevent
            @dragenter="dragenter($event)"
            @dragleave="clearDrag($event)"
            v-for="(project, index) in visibleProjects"
            :key="project.id"
            link
            @click="emitAllUsers(project, index)"
            class="projectItemSize project"
            id="projectlist"
            >
          <v-list-item-avatar  size="35" class="avatar">
            <v-img v-bind:src="returnImage(project,project.image)" />
          </v-list-item-avatar>
          <v-list-item-title class="project">
            {{ project.name }}
          </v-list-item-title>
         </v-list-item>
 </v-list-item-group>
```

And this is my method:

```
dragenter (evt) {
      const event = evt.target
      if (event.id === 'projectlist') {
        event.style.background = '#0061ff'
        event.style.color = 'white'
      }
    }
```

EDIT: The left picture below shows, that the background of the list-item have not changed, when dragging the item over the title.

[image]

Comment: Trying doing a `console.log` inside `dragEnter` handler inside `if` statement and check if anything is printing?

Comment: It is, but not when hovering over the title/image.. I just edited my question.

Comment: I am not understanding, you want it to change when you drag an item over something and trigger the `dragenter` event, or when your cursor is over it triggering the `mouseover` event?

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion. I mean by dragging an item over the list-item and triggering the dragenter-event.  So the color of the background does not change when I drag the item over the title of the list-item.